# Salesforce Community Portal

Tags: sandbox, community, sandbox-refresh

I have a Salesforce Community Portal. On the production 20 Users are using Community Licenses. I have recently got the access to a refreshed sandbox and there the number of Community Licenses used is 0. Is it because there is no data in account and contact or am I missing something ?

Comment: I think license is used when users are active, check the same

Comment: Community Users are very closely coupled with Contacts. If your Sandbox is a Dev sandbox, you won't have any Contacts, and hence no Community Users either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing that you are creating developer sandbox. In a developer sandbox the Account & Contact data is not copied over. Thus, the community users are not copied over.

If you want to see your production community user in a sandbox, you'll need to create a full sandbox copy.